# Streaming frames from the screen, generating a video

Tags: python, image, streaming, opencv, frames

If I want to refresh the image I have to keep closing the window to refresh it. Is it possible without keep closing the window?
Here is the code:

```
import numpy
import cv2
from PIL import ImageGrab
while True:

    img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(765,155,1135,195))
    img_np = numpy.array(img)
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(img_np, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imshow("frame",frame)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cv2.waitKey(0)` waits without timeout, replace it with `cv2.waitKey(time_in_msec)`.

Example for refreshing at about 10Hz:

```
import numpy
import cv2
from PIL import ImageGrab

while True:
    img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(765,155,1135,195))
    img_np = numpy.array(img)
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(img_np, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imshow("frame",frame)
    cv2.waitKey(100)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

See [waitKey](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=waitkey) dcomentation:

> `imshow`
>   Displays an image in the specified window.
>
> Note This function should be followed by waitKey function which displays the image for specified milliseconds.
>   Otherwise, it won’t display the image.
>   For example, waitKey(0) will display the window infinitely until any keypress (it is suitable for image display).
>   waitKey(25) will display a frame for 25 ms, after which display will be automatically closed.